# Firebase Cloud Functions set value operation deletes the trigger originating node

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

[image]

Hello, above is my simple data structure in firebase's realtime db. I'm working on a simple cloud function that will listen to update in a user node 'score' property and update the 'averageScore' field that sits higher up the hierarchy.

Here's my onWrite callback:

```
.onWrite((change, context) => {

    if (!change.before.exists() || !change.after.exists()) {
        return null;
    }

    const beforeScore = parseFloat(change.before.val()['score']);
    const afterScore = parseFloat(change.after.val()['score']);
    const userRef = change.after.ref;

    var promises = [
        userRef.parent.parent.child('userCount').once('value'),
        userRef.parent.parent.child('averageScore').once('value')
    ];

    return userRef.transaction(() => {
        return Promise.all(promises).then((snapshots) => {
            const userCount = snapshots[0].val();
            const averageScore = snapshots[1].val();

            const currentAverage = (( ( averageScore * userCount ) - beforeScore + afterScore ) / userCount ).toFixed(2);

            return userRef.parent.parent.child('averageScore').set(currentAverage);
        });
    });

});
```

If I update userId 1234's **score**, the **averageScore** field is updated correctly per this code. However, the whole user Id node 1234 gets **DELETED** following this update. This is quite a head scratcher and hoping to get some insight from the community on what I might be doing wrong.

Cheers.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding how transactions work with Realtime Database.  There's a lot of things going wrong here (including the use of `set()` inside a transaction, and reaching outside the location of the transaction itself.

Comment: @DougStevenson yup totally right on my misunderstanding. Figured it out and answer posted. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
.onWrite((change, context) => {

    if ( !change.before.exists() || !change.after.exists()) {
        return null;
    }

    const beforeScore = parseFloat(change.before.val()['score']);
    const afterScore = parseFloat(change.after.val()['score']);
    const crowdStatsRef = change.after.ref.parent.parent.child('crowdStats');

    return Promise.all( [
        crowdStatsRef.child('userCount').once('value'),
        crowdStatsRef.child('averageScore').once('value')
    ]).then((snapshots) => {
        return crowdStatsRef.transaction((crowdStatsNode) => {

            if (crowdStatsNode) {
                const userCount = snapshots[0].val();
                const averageScore = snapshots[1].val();

                const currentAverage = (( ( averageScore * userCount ) - beforeScore + afterScore ) / userCount ).toFixed(2);
                crowdStatsNode.score = parseFloat(currentAverage);
            }

            return crowdStatsNode;
        }, (error, committed, snapshot) => {
            if (error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Misunderstood how transactions worked. The object you're locking onto must be returned in the callback function. Also, a null check in that callback function is essential here.

Examples are noted here:
https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/01/keeping-our-promises-and-callbacks_76.html